# Visibility variables in a for with Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, variables, scope

I have this code:

```
let notificationList = angular.fromJson(response.data);
console.log(notificationList); /**FIRST PRINT**/
let numberOfMenuItems = notificationList.numberOfMenuItems;
console.log(" I have "+numberOfMenuItems+" Items"); /**SECOND PRINT**/
for(var i = 1; i <= numberOfMenuItems; i++){
    console.log(notificationList); /**THIRD PRINT**/
    let menuItemName = notificationList.('menuItemName'+i);
    console.log(menuItemName);
    let quantity = notificationList.('quantity'+i);
    console.log(quantity);
}
```

But when i run my code, the FIRST PRINT say me:

```
{
    "numberOfMenuItems"="1",
    "menuItemName1"="string1",
    "quantity1"="2",
}
```

The SECOND PRINT say me:

```
I have 1 Items
```

and it's correct!
The THIRD PRINT say me:

```
notificationList [Object object]
```

and then menuItemName and quantity are undefined.. I don't change anything of notificationList before the cycle..but when i enter in it, notificationList seems changed because console say me a different things than before..
What i am doing wrong? I hope someone can help me! thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 2 lines are wrong:

```
let menuItemName = notificationList.('menuItemName'+i); 
let quantity = notificationList.('quantity'+i);
```

Replace them with:

```
let menuItemName = notificationList['menuItemName'+i]; 
let quantity = notificationList['quantity'+i];
```

How does your `notificationList` look like?

Comment: Thank you it works!! but why also work this??:

    let numberOfMenuItems = notificationList.numberOfMenuItems;

Comment: I'm not sure I get this question but in your wrong quantity and itemName assignments you have syntax errors. In js to access a property of an object you need to use ```object[propertyName]``` and not ```object.(propertyName)``` as you did.